# Error 3031 mapping fragments starting at line 439:Non-nullable column

Tags: sql, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

```
Error 3031: Problem in mapping fragments starting at line 439:Non-nullable column D_LINK.CARTON_QTY in table D_LINK is mapped to a nullable entity property.
```

I have a view `D_LINK` with a column

```
CARTON_QTY(int, not null)
```

I dont understand where is my problem
do i have to make it null \ how?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The error says that your column in the table / view is not nullable but the property of the class in entity model is nullable. They must both be either nullable or not nullable.

Comment: how do i change the column in the table to be nullable? (in the edmx not in the database - I have already changed it their)

Comment: this is super annoying. i changed my table column from nullable to non nullable, and updated my model from database. but it looks like it's not switching the entity property to non nullable and i keep getting this error

Comment: @SonicSoul I have the same problem. It's annoying. I fixed it by removing all the tables from the designer and re-adding them.

Answer (score 9):

refresh the table in your edmx from your database (In model browser, right-click-->Update Model From database --> update tab --> select your table -->click update)

Answer (score 2):

Just delete that particular table from the model and add it again. That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I got this issue after changing a none-nullable column to a nullable one. 
What solved it for me was the following:

1. Manually edit the column and the link the column had to another table to (0...1) in the .edbx file.
2. After the manual edit do a update table like DRM described.

One of the actions alone did not solve my problem(feels like a glitch). Hope this can help someone.

Comment: In my case (EF 3.5 still) the hack was in the .edmx.

Answer (score 0):

This is on EF 4.5 that I am finding this, previous versions may not have this exact problem.

DRM mentions the way to update it, but I have found that sometimes even when you update it some of the minor changes like switching required fields or changing the field names it doesn't change them in the edmx even though you update it.  Therefore your data models don't match the database exactly.

I have found the best way to ensure your edmx entity models are correct is to delete the edmx and re-add it.  After doing the database first approach on EF 4.5 I think that Entity seems to play more nicely with the code first approach instead of database first.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the record. Only **undo** removes the error otherwise rebuilt table

Answer (score 0):

I got it solved by 
1. Delete the particular tables from the model 
2. Right click on the model, select Update model from the database, select the deleted tables and click finish.